# Android: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered` when onStop() called

Tags: android, service

I have an applications which is bound to a long running `Service`.
I need to make sure that when the user navigates away from the `Activity` the `Service` stops.

Therefore I implemented the `onStop()` to close the service:

here is the code:

```
@Override    
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();     
if(mService!=null)mService.stop();
stopService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));
unbindService(mConnection);
stopService(intent);

}
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.quotes/com.example.quotes.Quotes}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.example.quotes.Quotes$1@40cebd80
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3451)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.example.quotes.Quotes$1@40cebd80
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:921)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1451)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:484)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at com.example.quotes.Quotes.onDestroy(Quotes.java:420)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5273)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1110)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3438)
02-22 11:42:44.393: E/AndroidRuntime(1006):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `onStop()` is not for you to stop a Service, its for System to notify that service is being stopped.

Comment: @User117 Thanks! BUT the `onStop()` in the code is in the Activity, it gets called when the user navigates from the Activity, and in that `onStop()` I need to stop and disconnect the service calling `stopService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));` and  `unbindService(mConnection);`

Comment: If you called `startService()` anywhere, you need to call `stopService()`. If you just bind to service, then service will automatically stop when all clients have un-binded from it.

Comment: which means if i use unbindService(serviceConn); i dont need to use stopService() method @S.D. ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point is that after the `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` was called subsequently.

But my `onDestroy()`
was:

```
@Override    
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy(); 
    if(mService!=null)mService.stop();
    stopService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class));
    unbindService(mConnection);
    stopService(intent);        

 }
```

Therefore I was trying to close the Service **twice**. But the service was **already disconnected** in `onStop()`.

Thanks anyway

Comment: One thing I just found useful to do is to use your call to `stopService(Intent)` as a boolean in an if statement holding the `unbindService(ServiceConnection)` call. `stopService(Intent)` returns false if the service is already gone.

Comment: stopping it twice? what about if inside the onStop() method I put -> super.onStop(); and also unbindService(myservice); ? Because it still throws the same error like you had @LisaAnne

Comment: i get mservice null every time null