# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@427aa108

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I see this error repeatedly in my log but can't find any resource online to explain it. Also, searching for "BluetoothMap Android" does not return the BluetoothMap class. I guess it must be something in the codebase but not well known to the developers. So far this error seems to not cause crash, but anyone knows why it happens and how to remove it?

```
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@427aa108
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:931)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1595)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:66)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

A more complete log is here:

```
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 D BluetoothAdapterService: Profile still running: com.android.bluetooth.hdp.HealthService
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothHidServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth HID Interface...
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W bt-btif : cleanup: HH disabling or disabled already, status = 0
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothHidServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth GID callback object
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 D BluetoothAdapterService: Profile still running: com.android.bluetooth.pan.PanService
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothHealthServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth Health Interface...
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothHealthServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth Health object
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 D BluetoothAdapterService: Profile still running: com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothPanServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth PAN Interface...
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164  1164 W BluetoothPanServiceJni: Cleaning up Bluetooth PAN callback object
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164 17587 D BluetoothAdapterState: CURRENT_STATE=PENDING, MESSAGE = STOPPED, isTurningOn=false, isTurningOff=true
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164 17587 D BluetoothAdapterProperties: Setting state to 10
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164 17587 I BluetoothAdapterState: Bluetooth adapter state changed: 13-> 10
01-10 17:22:44.528  1164 17587 D BluetoothAdapterService: Broadcasting updateAdapterState() to 1 receivers.
01-10 17:22:44.528   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Message: 60
01-10 17:22:44.528   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: MESSAGE_BLUETOOTH_STATE_CHANGE: prevState = 13, newState=10
01-10 17:22:44.528   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothStateChange(false) to 17 receivers.
01-10 17:22:44.538   859  9000 D BluetoothHeadset: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538  1164 17587 I BluetoothAdapterState: Entering OffState
01-10 17:22:44.538   584   606 D BluetoothA2dp: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 D BluetoothHealth: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538   584   606 D BluetoothHeadset: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 D BluetoothMap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@427aa108
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:931)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1595)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:66)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 E BluetoothMap:      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 D BluetoothA2dp: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18168 D BluetoothInputDevice: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18202 D BluetoothHeadset: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538   859  1235 D BluetoothHeadset: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538   859   877 D BluetoothHeadset: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 D BluetoothInputDevice: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1971 D BluetoothPan: BluetoothPAN Proxy object disconnected
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1971 D PanProfile: Bluetooth service disconnected
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 D BluetoothMap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@42788e88
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:931)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1595)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:66)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-10 17:22:44.538 18157 18169 E BluetoothMap:      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 D BluetoothMap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$2@42574750
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:931)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1595)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:529)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.BluetoothMap$1.onBluetoothStateChange(BluetoothMap.java:66)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothStateChangeCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothStateChangeCallback.java:55)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1984 E BluetoothMap:      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-10 17:22:44.538  1971  1983 D BluetoothPbap: onBluetoothStateChange: up=false
01-10 17:22:44.538   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Calling onBluetoothServiceDown callbacks
01-10 17:22:44.538   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Broadcasting onBluetoothServiceDown() to 8 receivers.
01-10 17:22:44.548   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: unbindAndFinish(): android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy@42a56358 mBinding = false
01-10 17:22:44.548   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Sending unbind request.
01-10 17:22:44.548   584   606 D BluetoothManagerService: Bluetooth State Change Intent: 13 -> 10
```

Comment: When is the exception occuring? When you're attempting to unbind the service? (See this post for one possible reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15024341/804773)

Comment: Hi thank you. I see that in her case she get that error by double-unbinding the service. I am using bluetooth in my code, but this error seems to not point to anywhere in my code. I wonder how can I find the place where I double-unbind?